# Dynkin Diagram $SU(n)$

Tags: lie-algebras, root-systems, dynkin-diagrams

The goal is to give the Dynkin diagram of $SU(n)$. One can show that the complexification of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ is given by $\mathfrak{G}_{\mathbb{C}}=\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ (thus the traceless matrices). Moreover one can show that if $\mathfrak{t}$ is the set of all diagonal matrices, that then $\mathfrak{t}$ is a maximal torus of $\mathfrak{g}$. The first step we have to make is the determine what the root system $R=R(\mathfrak{g}_{\mathbb{C}},\mathfrak{t})$ is. Therefore define $\epsilon_k:\mathfrak{t}\rightarrow i\mathbb{R}$ by $\epsilon_k(X)=X_{kk}$ (thus the map takes the $k^{th}$ diagonal element of $X$. Furthermore let $E_{ij}$ $(i\neq j)$ be the matrix with $1$ on the $(i,j)$-place and zero else.

The first claim we make is that $\mathbb{C}E_{ij}$ is a root space. Thus we have to find a linear functiona $\alpha$ such that $[H,\mu E_{ij}]=\alpha(H)\mu E_{ij}$ for $H\in\mathfrak{t}$ and $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$. I thought that this functional has to be the following $\alpha(H)=(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)$ with $\lambda_i,\lambda_j$ the values on the diagonal (and the $i$ and $j$ comming from $E_{ij}$). Thus my idea was that $R=\{\epsilon_i-\epsilon_j:i\neq j\}$. Is this a good idea? If so, then can someone explain how to write this down in a good way, so not where lies the mistake?

The following claim is that $E=i\mathfrak{t}^*$ together $R$ is a root system. This should be doable since the properties of a root system are not quiet difficult.

The next step is to determine a fundamental system $S$ of $R$ and to show what the reflections $s_{\alpha}$ $(\alpha\in S)$ are. Furthermore i hve to know what the Cartan integers of $S$ are to draw the good Dynkin diagram.

For the last steps I need some explainations. Is there someone who can help me with this topic?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Dynkin diagram of $SU(n+1)$ is the diagram of type $A_n$, because the Dynkin diagram of the Lie algebra $\frak{sl}(n+1)$ is the Dynkin diagram of the Lie algebra $\frak{su}(n+1)$. For details see for example [here](http://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4270/h12/notes12_1.pdf), or section $9.10.1$ [here](http://www.phys.nthu.edu.tw/~class/Group_theory/Chap%209.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how can i connect this with the construction note above?

Comment: You are on the right way. Now you have to compute the Cartan matrix, and then you are done. This has been explained very nicely in the literature, so look for Dynkin diagram of type $A_n$.